# Get PNG Image From Native Win32 Resource In .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, image, resources

A DLL file contains some images inside PNG resource type.

I can view the PNG images in softwares like Resource Hacker, Anolis Resourcer & Resource Tuner. Check this screenshot of Anolis Resourcer for more details:

[image]

Can someone tell me how do I get the PNG image no. 5220 from the DLL file and put it inside a PictureBox? I don't think APIs like LoadImage or LoadBitmap will work.

Comment: Is it an embedded resource or is it a resource file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// get the assembly containing the image
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

// set the picturebox image to read the embedded resource
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(
    assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("AssemblyName.test.png")
);
```

where `AssemblyName.test.png` is the fully qualified name of the embedded resource inside the assembly.

---

UPDATE:

It seems that you are trying to extract resources from a native assembly. You may take a look at the [following article](http://khason.net/blog/how-to-load-unmanaged-native-resources-from-managed-c-code/) which illustrates how this could be done using P/Invoke.

Comment: @AnonMouse, ok, I have updated my answer with a link to an article illustrating how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

A PNG image is not one of the standard Win32 resource types.  It is usually embedded as a binary blob with the named resource type "PNG", although that's not guaranteed.  By far the easiest way to figure this out is by opening the file with Visual Studio's File + Open + File command.  You'll see the embedded resources organized in a tree, hopefully with a descriptive name, right-click a candidate and select Export to save it to disk.

Doing this programmatically requires a lot of gritty pinvoke.  It is tricky because both the resource type and the resource ID can be either a string or an IntPtr so you'll need 4 overloads for FindResource.  In order, you'll need LoadLibraryEx() to load the file without executing any of its code.  FindResource to get a handle to the resource.  SizeOfResource to know how large it is.  LoadResource + LockResource to get a pointer to the resource data.  Marshal.Copy() to copy the resource data into a byte[].  Clean up with FreeResource and FreeLibrary.

Answer (score 4):

The link that Darin posted (which has consequently been marked as the answer) does not contain functional code. I've evaluated the code posted there (http://khason.net/blog/how-to-load-unmanaged-native-resources-from-managed-c-code/) and found that it does not work properly for any Bitmap image embedded in any win32 dll as a bitmap resource.

Additionally, Hans Passant leaves off a myriad of steps effectively rendering his post useless.

The only somewhat close solution that I've been able to find comes from an article written in 2004 for the XP Theme dll junk. You can find the 'GetResourcePNG' method in ThemeManager.cs here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/XPTaskBar.aspx

However, it should be noted that I've been having a lot of difficulty with this method, as the call to bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX); causes memory issues when trying to access pngs within authui.dll on my system

**Update:**

I've found the code listed here (http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Controls/Explorer_Bar/ExplorerBar_Control_Source_Code.asp) to be by far the most functional, produce the fewest errors and produces the fastest results. The code is written in c# even though the domain name would indicate otherwise. Using the two classes; ImageUtility and ResourceLibrary, you can easily pull a PNG out of a standard, non-.net resource library/dll:

```
    public static Bitmap GetStandardResourceBitmap(String dllName, String resourceId) {
        Bitmap result = null;

        using (ResourceLibrary library = new ResourceLibrary() { Filename = dllName }) {
            IntPtr hDib = library.GetResource(resourceId, ResourceLibrary.ImageType.IMAGE_BITMAP, ResourceLibrary.ImageLoadOptions.LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
            if (!hDib.Equals(IntPtr.Zero)) {
                result = ImageUtility.DibToBitmap(hDib);
                ImageUtility.DeleteObject(hDib);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I chose to have resourceId in my method a String, only because it doesn't require an overload and using numbered resource Ids is as simple as prepending a '#'.

```
GetStandardResourceBitmap("shell32.dll", "#632");
```

Cheers

Comment: I wasn't missing anything - you failed to read the entire thread. The code he posted does not work with resources within a win32 dll, nor is the code he linked to functional for resources from a standard win32 dll - which is what the author is targeting. If you read the entire post, you would have gleaned that. For non-PNG bitmap resources in a standard dll, Bitmap.FromResource is the method to use. However, PNGs not listed in the "PNG" resource type present other problems, as outline in the code I linked to.